# Linear equations with multidimensional matrices [Modified]

Tags: matlab, image-processing

There is a system of 3 linear equations composing of matrices which are represented by RGB image. Say

```
A = A1*x1 + A2*x2 + A3*x3    ......(Eq 1)
B=  A1*x4 + A2*x5 + A3*x6   ........(Eq 2)
C=  A1*x7 + A2*x8 + A3*x9   ........(Eq 3)
```

each are of equal dimension say 3D. I performed the following

```
A11=rgb2gray(A1);
x11=rgb2gray(x1);
A11 =double(A1) ; x11 = double(x11); b = A1*x1;

opts.UT = true; opts.TRANSA = false;
y1 = linsolve(x1,b,opts); 
imshow(y1);
```

% The objective is to obtain A1,A2,A3
On doing this, following issues have surfaced:
1. Error
The output y1 is not the same as A1, which should have been. Why is it so? Please help

Answer (score 0):

The R,G and B spaces are orthogonal. So you can solve each of those sets independently. The problem here is that `mtimes`, which is your matrix multiplication operator, doesn't accept 3D inputs.

To solve this, you can loop through each of R, G and B and use linsolve for each of the resulting 2D matrices. Normally, I wouldn't recommend loops for anything in MATLAB, but here, there won't be any discernable overhead as there are only 3 iterations in the loop.

Your answer will not be any different from what it would be if you were to solve them all in one go (if that were possible), because the three spaces are independent.

**EDIT**

The way you've written your equations, the `xi`'s form the coefficient matrix and `Ai`'s are the unknowns. The system of equations can be written compactly as `XY=Z`, where `X` is a 3D matrix composed of the coefficients, `xi` for each color space,`RGB`; `Y` is a 2D matrix, with a vector `[A1, A2, A3]'` in each color space, and `Z` is also a 2D matrix with vectors `[A, B, C]'` in each color space.

Assuming that the colorspace is the last dimension, you can try

```
[xPixels,yPixels,colorSpace]=size(X);
Y=zeros(yPixels,colorspace);
opts.UT=true; opts.TRANSA=false;

for i=1:colorspace
    Y(:,i)=linsolve(X(:,:,i),Z(:,i),opts);
end
```

You'll have to setup the matrices `X`, `Y` and `Z` according to your problem. It is helpful to keep the looped dimension (in this case, `colorspace`) as the outermost dimension, as otherwise, you'll have to use `squeeze` to remove the singleton dimensions.

Comment: @R.M: It will be highly appreciated if you kindly illustrate with the modified code. Will it be possible if i do something with immultiply?

Comment: @R.K: Its giving the same error ??? Error using ==> mtimes
Input arguments must be 2-D.

Error in ==> lineareq at 63 . Also, the assignment to the matrices X, Y,Z is done as Y =double(A1) ; X = double(x1); Z = X*Y;
Y =double(A1) ; X = double(x1); Z = X*Y;

Comment: like I said before, you cannot use matrix multiplication when you have a 3D matrix. I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to do the forward problem or the inverse problem? If you know the matrix `Y`, then why are you using `linsolve`? If it is matrix `Z` that you need, you'll still have to loop it through to do the multiplication.

Comment: @R.K.: I need to multiply 3D matrices(forward problem) and also make the operation reversible such that the A1,A2,A3 are obtained from the known x's. Then matrix multiplication would work only when converting them to gray scale?(rgb2gray)

Comment: @R.K.: If Z=X*Y works with gray scale then the looping for each channel will not be necessary. In which case how do I proceed since my code in the original Question still does not work for gray scales images. Your valuable examples and explanations are really helpful.

Comment: yes, looping won't be necessary for a grayscale image as it's 2D. The problem with the original code is that the order of the inputs to `linsolve` are not correct. To solve the inverse problem using `linsolve`, the command is `linsolve(X,Z,opts)`, whereas your code did `linsolve(Z,X,opts)`.

Comment: @R.M: Uhoo, I am not getting the original A1 upon solving the equation!! I have modified the code and worked with gray scale in the first part of Eq 1, still the result should have been equal to A1. Please see

Comment: @gavishna: The result need not always be equal. If your matrix, `X` is not full rank, i.e., the null space of the matrix is non-empty, the inverse problem will not always give you back the original `A1`. Do you get a warning saying "Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled"? What is the output of `isempty(null(X))` and `cond(X)`?

Comment: @R.M:isempty(null(X))=1 and cond(X)=1.2470e+005. Also there is no such warning Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. How is it possible to get back exactly the same matrix.Thank you for your time and patience.